# flutter bloc state not updating and i could not find any mistake

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc

Bloc File

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

part 'address_event.dart';
part 'address_state.dart';

class AddressBloc extends Bloc<AddressEvent, AddressState> {
  AddressBloc() : super(AddressInitial());

  @override
  Stream<AddressState> mapEventToState(AddressEvent event) async* {
    if (event is GetInput) {
      yield* _mapGetInputEventToState(event);
    }
  }

  @override
  Stream<AddressState> _mapGetInputEventToState(GetInput event) async* {
    yield AddressInitial(inputText: event.inputText);
  }
}
```

Event File

```
part of 'address_bloc.dart';

@override
abstract class AddressEvent {}

class GetInput extends AddressEvent {
  String inputText;

  GetInput(this.inputText);
}
```

State File

```
part of 'address_bloc.dart';

@override
abstract class AddressState {}

class AddressInitial extends AddressState {
  String? inputText;

  AddressInitial({this.inputText});
}
```

The UI File Bloc Part

```
BlocBuilder<AddressBloc, AddressState>(
                              bloc: addressBloc,
                              builder: (context, state) {
                                if(state is AddressInitial){
                                  return Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.location_on, size: 20),
                                      Space(24),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "Address",
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                  fontSize: 21),
                                            ),
                                            Space(4),
                                            if(textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) 
                                              Text(
                                                **"${state.inputText}",**
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            if(textEditingController.text.isEmpty) 
                                              Text(
                                                "2911, sec 9/11, Hisar",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Space(8),
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            showDialog(
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                                  return Dialog(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      height: 250,
                                                      width: 500,
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              20),
                                                      child:
                                                          SingleChildScrollView(
                                                        child: Column(
                                                          children: [
                                                            CustomTextField(
                                                                controller: textEditingController,
                                                                maxLines: 3,
                                                                title: 'Address',
                                                                hasTitle: true,
                                                                initialValue: '',
                                                                **onChanged:
                                                                    (value) {
                                                                      addressBloc.add(GetInput(textEditingController.text));
                                                                    }),**
                                                            CustomTextField(
                                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                                title: 'LandMark',
                                                                hasTitle: true,
                                                                initialValue: '',
                                                                onChanged:
                                                                    (value) {}),
                                                            ElevatedButton(
                                                              style: ElevatedButton
                                                                  .styleFrom(
                                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                                          Colors
                                                                              .white),
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                Navigator.pop(
                                                                    context);
                                                              },
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                'Save',
                                                                style: Theme.of(
                                                                        context)
                                                                    .textTheme
                                                                    .headline5!
                                                                    .copyWith(
                                                                        color: Colors
                                                                            .black),
                                                              ),
                                                            )
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                });
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                
                                }
                                else{
                                  return SizedBox(height: 10,);
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

I have put the bloc part in the UI in ** please so it why it isn't updating in the screen even if I add some value to the address dialog box.
dialog box pops up to edit the address but after i click the save button the value of the address input part is not changed. i also tried adding tehe same bloc code in the onPressed of save but it doesn't seem to work anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to get rid of the textEditingController, on your CustomTextField on the on Changed property try this:

```
onChanged: (value)=>  addressBloc.add(GetInput(value))
```

Would also recommend to initialize the TextEditingController before your BlocBuilder, and to assign the value to the controller on the builder method of the BlocBuilder.

Would also recommend on the state class to extend Equatable so you can declare what makes an event different from another and the BlocBuilder can respond to it.

Edit:
Using the following:

```
bloc: ^8.1.1
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
equatable: ^2.0.5
```

address_bloc.dart:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'address_event.dart';
part 'address_state.dart';

class AddressBloc extends Bloc<AddressEvent, AddressState> {
  AddressBloc() : super(AddressState.initial()) {
    on<AddressChanged>((event, emit) {
      emit(state.copyWith(address: event.address));
    });
  }
}
```

address_event.dart:

```
part of 'address_bloc.dart';

abstract class AddressEvent extends Equatable {
  const AddressEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AddressChanged extends AddressEvent {
  final String address;
  const AddressChanged({required this.address});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [address];
}
```

address_state.dart:

```
part of 'address_bloc.dart';

class AddressState extends Equatable {
  final String address;
  const AddressState({required this.address});

  const AddressState.initial() : address = '';

  AddressState copyWith({String? address}) {
    return AddressState(address: address ?? this.address);
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Code example:

```
//Code example
    final addressBloc = BlocProvider.of<AddressBloc>(context);
    return BlocBuilder<AddressBloc, AddressState>(builder: ((context, state) {
      //state is your addressState object which has the property of address
      //you can call it with state.address to read it
      // when it changes, BlocBuilder will execute again and update the value.
      if (state.address != '') {
        //do something when in the initial condition
      }
      
      return TextFormField(
        initialValue: state.address,
        onChanged: (value) => addressBloc.add(AddressChanged(address: value)),
      );
    }));
```

Comment: nope not working

Comment: if i do that
onChanged part then when i use it above how do I check on the box if something was saved in textcontroller or not

Comment: The value is still not being added to the controller it is showing it as null

Comment: I would get rid of the controller and instead use the state.inputText property inside the Bloc Builder to get the text.

Comment: Since you are displaying in a showDialog, you can use the initial value property (set it to state.inputText) to display the current value when you open it again.

Comment: plz tell how to use state.inputText

Comment: added code example, hope it helps @PulkitAggarwal